# What is a regex to check to see if some text contains only URLs?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that checks if some text only contains urls and whitespaces and nothing else so:

```
http://www.google.com http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

would match, but:

```
http://www.google.com and http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

would not match.

Is this possible?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Depends on your rules that define a "url"

Comment: Does the last URL followed by whitespace?

Comment: im using ruby, the last url may or may not be followed by a whitespace ideally, but in practice, no, it probably never will be. For a url definition, I'll probably keep it loose, like `/http\S+/` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this regex (only test if that is between spaces begin with http://):

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/\S++\s*+)++$/ =~ text
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby already has a method to extract URLs, so that's a great starting place, rather than reinventing a working wheel:

```
require 'uri'

[
  'http://www.google.com http://www.stackoverflow.com',
  'http://www.google.com and http://www.stackoverflow.com'
].each do |url|
  print url
  if url.split.all? { |u| !URI.extract(u).empty? }
    puts " contains only URLs"
  else
    puts " doesn't contain only URLs"
  end
end
```

Which, after running, is:

```
http://www.google.com http://www.stackoverflow.com contains only URLs
http://www.google.com and http://www.stackoverflow.com doesn't contain only URLs
```

This doesn't support all [the recognized URL schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html), but it is a starting point. You can specify which you want by passing an array of schemes to [`extract`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract). You can get the IANA's permanent list using:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html'))
schemes = doc.at('table table').search('tr').map{ |tr| tr.at('td').text }[1..-1]
```

Comment: really nice explanation. I also messaged you one of the nokogiri related question. Could you answer of that confusion?

Comment: here also `'table table'` means? basically what signature is it? where I can found such things,when should I think to use such notations?

Comment: It means, "read the Nokogiri documentation to learn about [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) and [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) and [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css)".

Comment: no sir. I know this. but talikng about the syntax inside it say,- `dive.foo`,some times `div#foo`, now your `table table`... and more I have seen in another questions. I want to see the source of those when to use `.`,`#` etc?

Comment: Then you don't know it. `at`, `at_css` and `css` take what kind of selectors? Search for information on those, and learn them.

Answer (score 0):

```
words.split.all? { |word| word.match(/^http:/) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for any URL and the string should be URLs with single white-space as URLs separator only

Look at this [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhcJzO/1)

```
(((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)\s){1,}((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)$
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html
- http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: "any URL"... That URL only checks a very small subset of [the available recognized schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html).

Comment: In practical way, it does not require all the regarded list. However, thank you for the valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex, please try this:

```
(?< protocol>\w+):\/\/(?< domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*
```

Please remove the space before 'protocol' and 'domain'.

Split the string with the whitespaces, and check each string if it is match with the regex above.

Hope it helps!